# Probability that the machines are broken down

Tags: probability

I have a problem of probability as below:

A company has 4 machines with the probability of being broken down in a day is $0.01$, $0.05$, $0.1$ and $0.1$ respectively.

a. In one random day with one-machine observation,what is the probability that machine is broken down?

b. When $2$ machines are tested, there is exactly one broken machine. What is the probability that the broken one is the first one?

For the first question, I have done like this:

Call $A$ is the probability one machine is chosen, $P(A) = \frac{1}{4}$

Call $H_{i}$ is the probability that the $i^{\text{th}}$ machine is broken $\rightarrow$ $P(A.H_{i})$ is the probability exactly one $i^{\text{th}}$ machine is broken.

I just think that the answer wil be the sum of all $P(H_i)$ but I still really confused here. I really need your help to check for me

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to part A is correct, namely

$(1/4) [ .01 + .05 + .1 + .1].$

Part B should be solved with **intuition** rather than math.

Suppose that there were two pieces of paper, each with a number.  One of the numbers is 0, and the other number is 1.  You choose one of the two pieces of paper at random.  You are then handed the piece of paper, and you look at it.  What are the chances that you chose the paper with the larger number?

Now, vary the problem.  Instead of handing you the piece of paper that you chose, a mediator first looks at that piece of paper, and then looks at the 2nd piece of paper.  Then he announces whether you chose the paper with the larger number.

Now vary the problem again.  This time the mediator looks at the **other** piece of paper first.  Obviously, the answer to all 3 questions is (1/2).

By the exact same intuition, the answer to part B is (1/2).